# $P(A∩B'∩C) $ given $P(A∩B∩C), P(A∩C) $ and $P(B∩C)$

Tags: probability

Having

- $P(A∩B∩C) = \frac {1}{10}$
- $P(A∩C) = \frac 15$
- $P(B∩C) = \frac 25$

What is the probability of $A∩B'∩C$ , where B' is the complement of B?

I tried to write $A∩B'∩C $ as $(A∩C) - (A∩B∩C)$ and then I calculated the probability doing

$ P(A∩C) - P(A∩B∩C) = \frac 15 - \frac {1}{10} = \frac {1}{10}$

I am not sure if this is possible because I don't know if the probability of the subtraction of two events is equal to the subtraction of probabilities.

Comment: Yes you are right. The probability of the subtraction is equal to the subtraction of the probabilities if the event you are subtracting is contained in the other.

Answer (score 3):

If events $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, then the probability of $X\cup Y$ is the sum of their probabilities. Your subtraction law is just a rearrangement of this, so it's good!

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to proceed as you did because of the following:

- $C = (B\cap C) \cup  (B'\cap C)$ as disjoint union
- $\Rightarrow A\cap C = (A \cap B\cap C) \cup  (A \cap B'\cap C)$ as disjoint union

Now, you can use the additivity of probability for disjoint events:
$$P(A\cap C) = P(A \cap B\cap C) + P(A \cap B'\cap C)\Rightarrow \boxed{P(A \cap B'\cap C) = P(A\cap C) - P(A \cap B\cap C)}$$